# Magento 2.3 - Database Backup not working

Tags: magento2, database, backup

I want to backup my database on a daily basis.
i did following setup in my magento admin panel.
https://prnt.sc/odgzhv
But no backups are generated in magento/var/backups folder.
Is there any thing else need to be done?
I monitored for 2 days but no backups are generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Check your cron is working or not @Nafisa

Comment: i think it is working. how can i check that

Comment: You can check cron status in "cron_schedule" table in database.

Comment: @SanjayGohil Sorry my cron is not running.
how to enable cron?

Comment: Remove all records from "cron_schedule" table and run "php bin/magento cron:run" command fusing ssh then reindex and flush cache and check cron status in "cron_schedule" table.

Comment: i am getting this error.......In Filesystem.php line 168:
                                                                                                     
  Invalid Document                                                                                   
  Element 'job': Duplicate key-sequence ['cashback'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniqueJobName'.  
  Line: 25                                       
cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]

Comment: My cron is working but still backups are not getting generated

Answer (score 0):

The Magento backup feature is disabled by default. To enable, enter the following CLI command:

bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1